# Does anyone know how to prove or disprove that for all even integers $k$ that there exists a prime number $n$ such that $n+k$ & $n-k$ are both prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

This problem came into my head while working on something similar. There was a similar question asked, but it was something slightly different. I’ve been stuck on this,unable to get any progress since I’m on holiday. I first thought about the fact that there are infinitely many primes, and that if these were randomly dispersed that the problem above should be true, but realised that that hasn’t been solved, then I moved onto brute force, but found no counterexample, asked ai and discord server and still no progress. Anyone got anything at all?

Comment: This is an unsolved problem, closely related to [Polignac's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polignac%27s_conjecture).

Comment: Think about these numbers mod $3$. If $k$ isn't a multiple of $3$, one of the numbers $n-k$, $n$ and $n+k$ must be - which is a problem for primality. The only prime which is a multiple of $3$ is, of course, $3$. So if we find an even $k$ (that's not a multiple of $3$) such that either $3+k$ or $3+2k$ is not a prime, we've got a counterexample. The smallest such $k$ is $k=16$.

Comment: There's a related problem. All primes greater than 2 are one more or less than a multiple of 4. All primes greater than 3 are one more or less than a multiple of six. More generally, not only is there an infinite number of primes, they break down evenly into allowed equivalence classes. If $p\equiv m \pmod{n}$ , then there are countably many such primes in equal proportion holding $n$ constant. This can be proven using the Riemann Zeta Function.

Comment: Ty, Chris Lewis. Idk why that wasn’t more obvious to me. I used pretty much the same method for the aforementioned variation of the problem and still didn’t think about it at all for this. Ty tho, now that this is gone, I have a lot more room to think about any other cases and how they would be distributed. I used literally this to prove that for k = 10, n = 13 (my age lol) is the only case

Answer (score 4):

Your statement is false for $k = 16$. 3 must divide one of the numbers $n - 16$, $n$, $n + 16$. This is only possible if $n - 16 = 3$, $n = 19$, $n + 16 = 35$.

Comment: Thank you, this should’ve been far more obvious to me, I used more or less the same method to prove that at k = 10, n = 13 was the only possible case. Idk why I didn’t apply it to this. Thanks again, you have no idea what this problem has done to me over the past 2 days, since I’m on holiday and can’t work on it.

Comment: On second thought, I may have realised something about the distribution. This always applies to any $k$ which ends in a $6$ and is not a multiple of $3$. I’ll work on the proof later, but thanks for this.